# background made up of particle-slider is not triggering due to other divs upon it

Tags: javascript, css, particles.js

I want to make a **background** made up of particle-slider using particle.js.

I have my div blocks, headers blocks, and some cards (containing info) on the page to display upon the background.

Since I have that particle-slider in the background and at the same time I have those blocks upon the slider, I am not able to hover upon the background particle-slider to show the particle-diffusion effects because those blocks are upon it. Because of those blocks I am unable to trigger the particle-diffusion effect when hovered upon it.

This illustration shows the background particle-slider logo and the blocks upon it (highlighted using pesticide extension):
[image: This illustration shows the background particle-slider logo and the blocks upon it (highlighted using pesticide extension):]

I have already tried to put that background to front (by adding the background code after all those blocks`s code) and then set the z-index to a negative interger....but that was a foolish way.

Please suggest something to fix my problem.

Comment: I created this pen some weeks ago: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/WNQQbdW it uses tsParticles, the upgraded and continued version of Particles.js, but you can solve your issue in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I brought a very simple approach to solve my problem.

I simply put that background particle-slider in front of all divs/blocks, and I just decreased that  opacity to 0.1 . Now it looks like a background (although is in the top of all blocks).

Answer (score 0):

If your blocks element do not have any `click` or `hover` event you can use following css to block elements to disable pointer events.

By adding following CSS even on hovering on blocks, the background hover will be triggered

```
.blocks {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: your code just removed/disabled the hover effects of those blocks. The background-particles are still covered by those blocks. The particles are not triggering the diffusion (upon hovering) at all.